# NoSuchMethodException not caught

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to catch the `NoSuchMethodException` in the following code:

```
try {
    method = currentClass.getMethod(arg1,arg2);
    break;
} 
catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

It's not getting caught. I've tried `catch (Throwable e)` and `catch (Exception e)` and `catch (NoSuchMethodError e)` but none of them worked.

Even though When I run the code the console shows a `NoSuchMethodException`, but it's not getting caught.

Comment: Why is this tagged spring-boot? Is this some spring-boot API or are we talking about regular reflection-based calls against java.lang.Class ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] and full stacktrace

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas sorry, accidentaly add it. will remove it

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: @Rex - You haven't used `getMethod` correctly. I have shown the correct way to use it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277543/10819573). Feel free to comment below the answer in case of an issue/doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `getMethod` in a **wrong** way. You must pass the name of the method and an array of arguments to it. Given below is an example of the correct way:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class[] arguments = new Class[1];
            arguments[0] = String.class;
            String.class.getMethod("concat", arguments);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Check the signature of [`String#concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) which takes an argument of type, `String`.

### Another example:

```
class MyClass {
    public void hello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }

    public int getSum(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class[] arguments = new Class[1];
            arguments[0] = String.class;
            MyClass.class.getMethod("hello", arguments);
            System.out.println("This one passed.");

            arguments = new Class[2];
            arguments[0] = int.class;
            arguments[1] = int.class;
            MyClass.class.getMethod("getSum", arguments);
            System.out.println("This one too.");

            // The following one will fail
            MyClass.class.getMethod("foo");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
This one passed.
This one too.
Error occured
```

### Update:

This update is based on [the following valuable comment from Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65277391/nosuchmethodexception-not-caught/65277543#comment115421175_65277543):

`getMethod` is a *varargs* method. There is no need to deal with arrays manually. You can use `String.class.getMethod("concat", String.class);`,
`MyClass.class.getMethod("hello", String.class);`, and `MyClass.class.getMethod("getSum", int.class, int.class);`. In fact, your `MyClass.class.getMethod("foo");` statement is already using that feature, as it doesn’t create the zero length `Class[]` array manually.

```
class MyClass {
    public void hello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }

    public int getSum(int x, int y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyClass.class.getMethod("hello", String.class);
            System.out.println("This one passed.");

            MyClass.class.getMethod("getSum", int.class, int.class);
            System.out.println("This one too.");

            // The following one will fail
            MyClass.class.getMethod("foo");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is misleading. He's not using the method name "arg1,arg2" - it's not in quotes. He's just passing two separate arguments. arg1 is a string (obviously) which contains the method name. arg2 is the argument for the method.

Comment: @k314159 - The answer is not misleading , but the first sentence was indeed not correct (which I have corrected now). The question was edited many times which caused the confusion. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `getMethod` is a *varargs* method. There is no need to deal with arrays manually. You can use `String.class.getMethod("concat", String.class);`, `MyClass.class.getMethod("hello", String.class);`, and `MyClass.class.getMethod("getSum", int.class, int.class);`. In fact, your `MyClass.class.getMethod("foo");` statement is already using that feature, as it doesn’t create the zero length `Class[]` array manually.

Comment: @Holger - Thanks for the valuable comment. I do not know why this comment did not appear in my notifications...I will check my notification settings. I've incorporated your comment as an update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Java exception hierarchy looks like so:

```
Throwable
 |      |
Error   Exception
        |
        RuntimeException
```

Errors are intended for signaling regarding problems in JVM internals and other abnormal conditions which usually cannot be handled by the program anyhow. So, in your code you are not catching them. Try to catch `Throwable` instead:

```
boolean result = false;
try{
   result =  Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
}
catch(Throwable e){
    Log.e("error","error");
}
```

Also it's a good idea to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Comment: The question says they _did_ try to catch both Throwable and Exception.

Comment: Thanks, but as I've mentioned above I've already tried that but it's not working

Comment: Ok... I might understood it wrong but what you are expecting here ??? `NoSuchMethodException` or `NoSuchMethodError`

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` is at jar level however other one occurs during the reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There are two variants to this

1. NoSuchMethodError - which has base class as Error - and is used by compiler to detect absence of the method used or at runtime when you lets say upgrade or downgrade a particular dependent jar and the method is not defined in the class in the new jar included.
2. NoSuchMethodException - which has base class as Exception, this you usually get when using reflection and the method with 'name' you are trying to access is not defined in that class.

However, both should be caught if you have catch block with Throwable as Throwable is the base of both Error and Exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class NoSuchMethodMethodTest
{   
    public static void checkIfMethodNotExist()
    {
        try
        {
            final NoSuchMethodMethodTest noSuchMethodMethodTest = new NoSuchMethodMethodTest();
            Class clazz = noSuchMethodMethodTest.getClass();
            final Method m = clazz.getMethod("demo", null);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            System.out.println("demo method not exist");
        }
    }

    public static void checkIfMethodExist()
    {
        try
        {
            final NoSuchMethodMethodTest noSuchMethodMethodTest = new NoSuchMethodMethodTest();
            Class clazz = noSuchMethodMethodTest.getClass();
            final Method m = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);

        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            System.out.println("main method exist");
        }
    }
}
```